Stages of speech or vak is applicable to all thoughts?
As their are four types of speech or vak in scriptures reference-1 and reference-2.
Philosophy, defines sound starts from muladhar chakra as para and moves to manipur as pashyanti and reaches to anahata chakra as madhyama and finally when we speak or audible as vaikhari.
I have one follow up question:

Is this vak philosophy applicable to all thoughts we speak? or its only supreme knowledge that comes like that( e.g. veda or agamas)?

